# Move to wishlist

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, wishlist

How can I make the product only be copied in wishlist, when I click move to wishlist from basket. Because on default it remove from basket but I want my product to be added in wishlist and also to stay in basket.
For moveing from wishlist to cart i have edited

`app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php` on row `518`
this piece of code from true to false

```
if ($item->addToCart($cart, false)) {
   $cart->save()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
}
```

but what about from cart to wishlist.
I have tried to find something to CartControler.php but there is nothing that I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on line `580` in the `app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php` controller, method `fromcartAction`.

The following piece of code removes the product from the quote.

```
$cart->getQuote()->removeItem($itemId);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i have't seen that it was very easy fix, only comment this line and line under and that's it. Works like a charm.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help. It's not the prettiest way to fix this but probably the only. Don't forget to close the question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The moving of products from cart to wishlist is done in `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Observer::processCartUpdateBefore`.
The line that removes the product from the cart when it is added to the wishlist is

```
$cart->getQuote()->removeItem($itemId);
```

But if you remove this please change the heading of the 'Move to wishlist' column to 'Copy to wishlist' so you won't confuse your customers.