# Switch ON/OFF products in Magento cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ajax, shopping-cart

I need customers to be able to switch on/off products to buy within their "My Cart" listing page (By default Magento let customers only remove items from the cart).

Is there a method or an extension to achieve this result? I'am attaching a picture as an example of what I need.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/move-to-wishlist

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to send removed items from cart to wishlist. I need to enable/disable products within the cart listing page.

Comment: It is not clear enough what should happen to products that are set to BUY LATER. Should they be added to cart immediatly after you checkout/place the order with all BUY NOW items? Or after that action they should go in a list similar to Wishlist?

Comment: @adjco, customers should be able to add as many products as they want to cart but enable/activate only some of them before proceeding with checkout and payment. Next time they login they should find products which they marked as "buy later" still in the cart (if cookies are not expired yet). I could not find any method or extension for this..

Comment: Addition for previous comment: For this particular project of mine however, it is not necessary that "buy later" items remain in the cart. So the ability for the client to switch on/off products from cart would be fine.

Comment: You would have to use a combination of item options coupled with a total model between subtotal and shipping as well as the obvious template file changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you  elaborate a little on this? Anyway shipping costs don't need to be calculated as for this project they will always be zero.